# PythonAnywhere issue with chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, pythonanywhere

have a working python script and tried migrating it to PythonAnywhere. It throws an wrror saying no element found in web scraping script. where as same code gets executed in the local machine.

```
service_log_path = "chromedriver.log"
service_args = ['--verbose']
choptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
choptions.add_argument('--headless')
choptions.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
choptions.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
choptions.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=choptions,service_log_path=service_log_path)
browser.get('xyz.com')
time.sleep(10)
username = browser.find_elements("id","abc")
```

Comment: Please include the exact and complete error message with traceback.

Comment: Mind that if you're using a free account you have a restricted internet access.  See [this help page](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/selenium/) for a working gist of code to test if the defaults are working fine on your account.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume it is a path issue. If it is going from a local machine to non-local. Your **PythonAnywhere** likely can not find `choptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()` or maybe `service_log_path = "chromedriver.log"`.